# jQuery filter options with value greater (less) than variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable values of options in select that are less than some number, which I do not know beforehand (it is set in another form element). I need something like code below, but with variable value of "variableInteger":

```
select.children().filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("value") > variableInteger;
}).each(function () {$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled')});
```

Is there some clever way to do it?

PS. variableInteger value is from another form element, which name is also known only at runtime.

Comment: What part of your code doesn't work? Are you having trouble getting the `variableInteger` value?

Comment: also, you are using `>` (greater than) when you requirements suggest you want `<` (less than)

Comment: musefan Thanks, that really was a problem with variableInteger. Thanks to Your comment I found it by myself :) Will set @tymeJV 's answer as correct as it also helped me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized. It's a typo. Neither the question nor the solution would be usable to anyone else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need for the `.each`, also make use of `prop` and `this.value` (no need for `$(this).attr("value");`)

```
select.children("option").filter(function() {
    return this.value > variableInteger;
}).prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: a good alternative, but I don't think you are answering the question. The OP's code should work ([as seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/fJ3vm/)), provided `select` and `variableInteger` variables have been set correctly